# Bound on the infinite sum of logarithms

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Is it possible to show that

$X=\frac 12 \log 3 + \frac 14 \log 4 + \frac 18 \log 5 + \frac{1}{16} \log 6 + \dots < \log 4$?

I think we can do

$\frac 12 X= \frac 14 \log 3 + \frac 18 \log 4 + \frac {1}{16} \log 5 + \frac{1}{32} \log 6 + \dots $

and subtract the two to get

$\frac 12 X=\frac 12 \log 3 + \frac 14 \log \frac 43 + \frac 18 \log \frac 54 + \frac{1}{16} \log \frac 65 + \dots $

So $X =  \log 3 + \frac 12 \log \frac 43 + \frac 14 \log \frac 54 + \frac{1}{8} \log \frac 65 + \dots < \log 3 + \frac 12 \log \frac 43 + \frac 12 \log \frac 54 + \frac{1}{2} \log \frac 65 + \dots$.

But the right most expression telescopes to $\frac 12 \log 3$ which is absurd! Where is my mistake and how to prove the original statement?

Comment: But why? I subtract the first $\frac 12 X$ from the first $X$ to get the second $\frac 12 X$ as $\frac 12 \log 3 + \frac 14 ( \log 4 - \log 3) +\frac 18 (\log5 - \log 4)+ \dots$ which looks like it is what I wrote?

Comment: That RHS does not telescope, it diverges ! (like the harmonic series)

Comment: I see. Is there another way to go about proving the original inequality then?

Answer (score 1):

**A numerical approach**:

As the exponential factor decreases quickly, only the first terms bring a significant contribution, and the tail can be estimated grossly.

We use

$$4\sum_{k=3}^\infty\frac{\log(k)}{2^k}<4\sum_{k=3}^\infty\frac{k}{2^k}=4=:S_3.$$

Then we replace the initial terms of the upper bound by the true terms and update the sum:

$$S_k=S_{k-1}-4\frac k{2^k}+4\frac{\log(k)}{2^k}.$$

We get
$$S_{3}=4.00000000000\cdots\\
S_{4}=3.04930614433\cdots\\
S_{5}=2.39587973461\cdots\\
S_{6}=1.97205947367\cdots\\
S_{7}=1.70904444050\cdots\\
S_{8}=1.55110413265\cdots\\
S_{9}=1.45859540674\cdots\\
S_{10}=1.40544872375\cdots\\
S_{11}=1.37538069677\cdots
$$

to be compared to

$$\log(4)=1.38629436112\cdots$$

(The sum converges to $1.33818851\cdots$, there is a $3.5\%$ margin.)

This is enough to prove the claim if you accept that the numerical computation is accurate (total rigor would ask to provide bounds on the truncation error).

An alternative approach is to write the upper bound $S_{11}$ as a sum of the initial estimate $4$ and the $22$ corrective terms, multiply by the largest denominator and take the exponential. In the end, you will have to prove that the exponential of a certain integer is smaller than a certain rational.

For the sake of illustration,

$$S_5=4-\frac32+\frac{\log(3)}2-\frac44+\frac{\log(4)}4-\frac58+\frac{\log(5)}8\stackrel?<\log(4)$$
is equivalent to
$$e^7\stackrel?<\frac{4^8}{3^44^25}.$$

With a good rational upper bound of $e$, say $\dfrac{1457}{536}$, this should be doable.

If I am right, one must check
$$\left(\dfrac{1457}{536}\right)^{13}\stackrel?<\frac{4^{512}}{3^{256}4^{128}5^{64}6^{32}7^{16}8^89^410^211}.$$

Comment: I've proved a better bound than $S_{11}$, namely $\ln 48 - \frac 52 \sim 1.371 $

Comment: even tighter $\frac{1}{144} \left(42 \zeta (3)-6 \pi ^2-75+8 \log ^3(2)+36 \log ^2(2)-4 \pi ^2 \log (2)+144 \log (2)\right)+\log (3)\sim \color{red}{1.3397}$

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM: $S_{11}$ is the first bound given by this method, and all the following are tighter. For instance $S_{17}=1.33911090114\cdots$. $S_{11}$ is enough to answer the post, so what's the point ?

Comment: Less computations and a formal proof ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM: sorry, I don't want to play "mine is better than yours" today.

Answer (score 1):

A rigorous approach: let $\displaystyle S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2^k}=2-\frac{1}{2^n}$

Performing an Abel transformation yields:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=3}^n \frac{\ln k}{2^k} &= \ln n S_n - \ln 3 S_2 + \sum_{k=3}^{n-1}\ln\left( \frac{k}{k+1}\right)S_k \\ &=2\ln n -\frac{\ln n}{2^n} + \sum_{k=3}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^k}\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right) -2\ln n +2\ln3 - \frac 74 \ln 3 \\ &= (2-\frac 74) \ln 3+ \sum_{k=3}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^k}\ln\left(1+\frac 1k\right)-\frac{\ln n}{2^n} \\ &\le (2-\frac 74) \ln 3+ \sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k2^k} \\ &\leq  \frac{\ln 3}{4} + \ln 2 - \frac{5}{8} 
\end{align}$$

Hence $$\sum_{k=3}^n \frac{\ln k}{2^{k-2}} \leq 4\left( \frac{\ln 3}{4} + \ln 2 - \frac{5}{8} \right) = \ln 48 - \frac 52 <\ln 4$$
I hope you bear no grudge if I don't prove $\displaystyle \ln 48 - \frac 52 < \ln 4$.

Checking with a pocket calculator, $\ln 48 - \frac 52 \sim 1.371$ while $\ln 4\sim 1.386$

---

You can refine the bound ad libitum if you use sharper inequalities for $\ln(1+x)$.

Using $\ln(1+x)\leq x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3$ and computing $\sum _{k=3}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2^k}\left(\frac{1}{3 k^3}-\frac{1}{2 k^2}+\frac{1}{k}\right)$. with Mathematica yields the much tighter bound:

$$\sum_{k=3}^n \frac{\ln k}{2^{k-2}}\leq \frac{1}{144} \left(42 \zeta (3)-6 \pi ^2-75+8 \log ^3(2)+36 \log ^2(2)-4 \pi ^2 \log (2)+144 \log (2)\right)+\log (3)$$

with $\frac{1}{144} \left(42 \zeta (3)-6 \pi ^2-75+8 \log ^3(2)+36 \log ^2(2)-4 \pi ^2 \log (2)+144 \log (2)\right)+\log (3)\sim \color{red}{1.3397}$

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram Alpha gives:

$$\int_1^\infty \log(x+2)/2^x dx = (4 \text{Ei}(-\log(2) x-\log(4))-2^{-x}\frac{\log(x+2))}{(\log(2))} \Big|_1^{\infty}$$
$$=(\log(3)-8 Ei(-\log(8)))/(\log(4)) = 1.04542...$$

where  $$\operatorname{Ei}(x)=-\int_{-x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}t\,dt.\,$$ is the exponential integral.

So by the integral test, you have your bound.

Edit: As someone pointed out in the comments, your right-hand-side series actually does not converge. The reason is that the partial sums all telescope to the form

$$\frac{1}{2}\log 3 + \frac{1}{2}\log n$$

which increases to infinity as n increases.